# What order are if statement conditions checked

Tags: swift, if-statement, conditional-statements, execution-time

I created an extension to check if values in an array are unique

```swift
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var seen: Set<Iterator.Element> = []
        return filter { seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that the check is `O(n)` complexity so within my function that uses this, I have a condition to disable this check.

```swift
if !valuesAreUnique && (values.unique() != values) {
    fatalError("Values must be unique.")
}
```

So my question is, will `values.unique()` always get executed in this if statement? In order to avoid that I would have to layer it like so, correct?

```swift
if !valuesAreUnique {
    if (values.unique() != values { // This is only ran if valuesAreUnique
        fatalError("Values must be unique.")
    }
}
```

Or if `valuesAreUnique` is `false`, then the checks just stop?

Comment: Yes, from left to right and once a condition fails it stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

via https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

> The *logical AND operator* (`a && b`) creates logical expressions where both values must be `true` for the overall expression to also be `true`.
>
> If either value is `false`, the overall expression will also be `false`. In fact, if the first value is `false`, the second value won’t even be evaluated, because it can’t possibly make the overall expression equate to `true`. This is known as *short-circuit evaluation.*